# Андроид Студио удаляет предыдущие сборки apk

Tags: android-studio

Одно время при компиляции apk, в папке debug оставались все ранее собранные сборки. Сейчас там только последняя сборка, которая постоянно перезаписывается.
Где надо настроить, что бы старые сборки оставались?

Comment: что-то я такого не помню если честно, и по-моему студия перезаписывает файлы всегда, как вариант можете переименовывать файл после сборки по дате например, и тогда студия их не будет убивать

Answer (score 0):

Так можно же каждую сборку сохранять просто в отдельной папке. Сбилдил - забрал с папки проекта и переложил в другую папку.